# Linear Algebra Addition Proof

Tags: linear-algebra

Let A and B both be m × n matrices and **x** and **y** both be n × 1 vectors.

Prove (A + B)**x** = A**x** + B**x**

Prove A(**x** + **y**) = A**x** + A**y**

Comment: This is the distributive law. However, since matrix algebra is not commutative, you must keep the order in which the matrices are multiplied.

Answer (score 1):

Use sum by index, The first one for coordinate $c_{ij}$ of $(A+B)$, $c_{ij}=a_i+b_j$ then it's obvious a sequence of row sums.

Samiliar for the second line. Use summation and it works.

I just thought of another stupid proofs, but it seemed to be interesting and just here for fun:
Make a matrix $Y=[y,[0]_2,[0]_3,...,[0]_n]$ where $[0]_i$ are just columns of $0$ s and use $n$ to match the dimesion of $A$. Then the $(A+B)y=(A+B)Y$ use distributive law and it's done.